# what did the author refer to with "in this way" in the following passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

**River pollution**

> A team from Cemagref in Lyon (FR) has identified a pertinent indicator of the level of pollution in rivers: the biofilm. A complex combination of bacteria, algae and fungi, the biofilm forms a viscous layer on immersed supports, such as the stones on a river bed. The biofilms are able to break down the pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments and modify **their** structure, diversity and functioning. Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, either definitively or temporarily. It is **in this way** that biofilms can serve as an early warning signal of pollution. It remains to characterize and distinguish the responses of biofilms to pollutants from those induced by environmental factors (current speed, physico-chemical composition, etc.). It is research of this kind that should help respond to the need set out in the Water Framework Directive to improve the ecological quality of European rivers.

They said that biofilm indicate river pollution in some way.I didn't get  **How does the biofilm indicate the level of pollution?**
One more question:**What do they refer to with "their" in the 5th line?**
[image]

Comment: This is a translation from the French right?

Comment: no it is from one of the research EU magazines.however the magazines may have French version but this passage is from English version

Comment: @Lambie Yes i think you are right

Comment: Ok, I broke it down for you.It's amazing how little things can really mess up a translation. This "in this way" here is a great example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited and corrected:

**A team from the Cemagref in Lyon (France) has identified a pertinent indicator of the level of pollution in rivers: biofilm. A complex combination of bacteria, algae and fungi, biofilm forms a viscous layer on immersed supports such as the stones on a river bed. Biofilms are able to break down pesticides that contaminate **aquatic environments** and modify **their structure**, diversity and functioning. Toxic substances, for example, can change the photosynthetic, respiratory or enzymatic activity of aquatic ecosystems, permanently or temporarily. **Thus**, biofilms can serve as an early warning signal of pollution. What remains to be characterized are the responses of biofilms to pollutants and how they differ from those induced by environmental factors such as current speed, physicochemical composition, among others. This kind of research should help formulate a response to the need set out in the Water Framework Directive to improve the ecological quality of European rivers.

Right. This was a translation as given in the question. Here are a list of the red flags that indicated this:

- Overuse and incorrect use of the deteminer **the**
- The sentence beginning **It remains to characterize**: it is completely wrong.
- The phrase: "in this way" is a mistranslation. The sentence shows a result, not a way of anything. The French was one of the phrases that can be translated "in this way", but it is would not be translated like that here. It might have been: C'est ainsi que, which basically means **thus** as in So. French uses many adverbial phrases like that to structure paragraph logic. (Too long to go into here)

- The pronoun *their* refers to the aquatic environments.
- In this way should be Thus or Therefore or Consequently for something like C'est ainsi here which has been mistranslated.

Cheers.

Comment: and one more thing did they not mean with breakdown eat?

Comment: @Muzaffar I cannot understand your question. What are you saying?

Comment: "Biofilms are able to break down pesticides that contaminate aquatic environments and modify their structure"here they said biofilms break down ... did they not mean with break down pestidicides = eat pesticides

Comment: @Muzaffar There are TWO different ideas: biofilms can break down pesticides AND biofilms are an early warning sign of pollution. Break down = make into smaller "bits".

Answer (score 0):

According to what I have just read, it makes me imagine that the biofilm ("A complex combination of bacteria, algae and fungi") does not form if the water is clean.

So **in this way** if the Biofilm is present, the water must be contaminated. Because at the beginning of the article it is said that biofilm is an indicator of pollution:

> A team from Cemagref in Lyon (FR) has identified a pertinent indicator of the level of pollution in rivers: the biofilm.

Comment: I think biofilms will be present because in the beginning they said biofilm forms a viscous layer in immersed supports such as the stones etc. To clarify answer I think we should understand what they meant with "their" in the 5th line.Instead of what are they using biofilm or pesticides or aquatic environments.